# GetFullPathNameW and long Windows file paths

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ntfs

In the Windows version of my current personal project, I'm looking to support [extended length filepaths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath). As a result, I'm a little confused with how to use the [GetFullPathNameW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to resolve the full name of a long filepath.

According to the MSDN (with regards to the lpFileName parameter):

> In the ANSI version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH characters. To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the Unicode version of the function and prepend "\?\" to the path. For more information, see Naming a File.

If I'm understanding this correctly, in order to use an extended length filepath with `GetFullPathNameW`, I need to specify a path with the `\\?\` prefix attached. Since the `\\?\` prefix is only valid before volume letters or UNC paths, this would mean that the API is unusable for resolving the full name of a path relative to the current directory.

If that's the case, is there another API I can use to resolve the full name of a filepath like `..\somedir\somefile.txt` if the resulting name's length exceeds `MAX_PATH`? If not, would I be able to combine `GetCurrentDirectory` with the relative filepath (`\\?\C:\my\cwd\..\somedir\somefile.txt`) and use it with `GetFullPathNameW`, or would I need to handle all of the filepath resolution on my own?

Comment: It doesn't sound reasonable that a function to find the full path, requires you to supply the full path. So why not try what the docs say. Maybe you'll be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: GetCurrentDirectory() is a unixism that's fundamentally MAX_PATH encumbered.  The native OS has no notion of relative paths or default directories, you must *always* supply it with a full path name.  You'll have to get rid of it to get ahead.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Wasn't really clear if you were suggesting I try `\\?\C:\my\cwd\..\somedir\somefile.txt` or `\\?\..\somedir\somefile.txt`, so I tried both. The first correctly resolves to `\\?\C:\my\somedir\somefile.txt`, (which answers part of my question) while the second incorrectly resolves to `\\?\somedir\somefile.txt`.

Comment: @HansPassant Just so I'm clear: we're talking about `GetCurrentDirectory`, not `_getcwd`, right? Assuming that's the case, you're saying that `GetCurrentDirectory` won't work for a long cwd path even if I use `GetCurrentDirectoyW` with an adequately sized buffer from a process that was created with `CreateProcess`'s `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter using the ```\\?\``` prefix? if so, that's a really obnoxious limitation.

Comment: Same thing, _getcwd() calls GetCurrentDirectory().  It is only a limitation for console mode programs, a programming model from the 1970s.  Microsoft has advised for a very, very long time that Windows programs should use AppData and the built-in known directories like Documents.  But sure, that model is very hard to get rid of and the library support in a C or C++ program certainly doesn't help.  Which *is* the ultimate reason why MAX_PATH is so difficult to get rid of, way too many programs have an implicit dependency on it with C-style char[] buffer declarations.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but I appreciate you taking the time to explain. The project I'm working on should still be doable - I'll just have to keep this in mind going forward.

Comment: This is an ugly hack, but for Vista+ you could try opening the file with `CreateFile` then use `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW` to resolve the path. Unfortunately that does require a file to actually exist, or the creation of a temp file at an arbitrary spot on your drive.

Comment: `GetFullPathName` is entirely string-based; it's just doing string manipulation on what you give it + whatever the current directory is. The paragraph about \\?\ is just boilerplate copy & paste - the function doesn't actually care what strings you pass it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. `GetFullPathNameA` is limited to `MAX_PATH` characters, because it converts the ANSI name to a `UNICODE` name beforehand using a hardcoded `MAX_PATH`-sized (in chars) `UNICODE` buffer. If the conversion doesn't fail due to the length restrictions, then `GetFullPathNameW` (or direct `GetFullPathName_U[Ex]`) is called and the resulting `UNICODE` name is converted to ANSI.
2. `GetFullPathNameW` is a very thin shell over `GetFullPathName_U`. It is limited to `MAXSHORT (0x7fff)` length in WCHARs, independent of the `\\?\` file prefix. Even without `\\?\`, it will be work for long (> `MAX_PATH`) relative names. However, if the `lpFileName` parameter does not begin with the `\\?\` prefix, the result name in the `lpBuffer` parameter will not begin with `\\?\` either.
3. if you will be use `lpBuffer` with functions like `CreateFileW` - this function internally convert `Win32Name` to `NtName`. and result will be depended from nape type (`RTL_PATH_TYPE`). if the name does not begin with `\\?\` prefix, the conversion fails because `RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U[_WithStatus]` fails (because if the path not begin with `\\?\` it will be internally call `GetFullPathName_U` (same function called by `GetFullPathNameW`) with `nBufferLength` hardcoded to MAX_PATH (exactly `2*MAX_PATH` in bytes – NTDLL functions use buffer size in bytes, not in `WCHAR`s). If name begin with `\\?\` prefix, another case in `RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U[_WithStatus]` is executed – `RtlpWin32NtNameToNtPathName`, which replaces `\\?\` with `\??\` and has no `MAX_PATH` limitation

So the solution may look like this:

```
if(ULONG len = GetFullPathNameW(FileName, 0, 0, 0))
{
    PWSTR buf = (PWSTR)_alloca((4 + len) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    buf[0] = L'\\', buf[1] = L'\\',  buf[2] = L'?', buf[3] = L'\\';
    if (len - 1 == GetFullPathName(FileName, len, buf + 4, &c))
    {
        CreateFile(buf, ...);
    }
}
```

So we need to specify a path with the `\\?\` prefix attached, but not before GetFullPathName - after!

For more info, read this - [The Definitive Guide on Win32 to NT Path Conversion](http://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html)

Comment: Upvoted just for the sheer level of detail, the sharing of knowledge. Though think it's a bit risky to assume that the internal implementation is the same in all Windows versions. Is it?

Comment: Win32 to NT Path Conversion will be always. however thin details of this convertation really can be changed from version to version. some win32 paths at all incorrect converted. in general, if use Win32 path - we have MAX_PATH practic limitation. for example we cannot create process from exe , if it absolute path length exceeded MAX_PATH. if need use long path names without any limitations or some special paths - need use NT paths (native) and ntdll API

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful. Hope you don't mind - I submitted an edit up to clean up the English a bit on the first two points.

Answer (score -1):

Just to update with the current state:

> Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, MAX_PATH limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior. To enable the new long path behavior, both of the following conditions must be met: ...

For the rest, please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57624626/3736444