# fopen fails to open a file due to long absolute path

Tags: c, path, fopen

I use fopen to open some files given their absolute path. It opens most of the files but some of them don't.

I thought it was because of the file itself but when I manually shorten the name of the folder which contains it there is no problem with opening it.

Is there a way to deal with this without having to rename that folder?

**EDIT**

Just mention I'm not working in Windows, but Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening long file names in Windows using fopen with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829691/opening-long-file-names-in-windows-using-fopen-with-c)

Comment: Please show your code and the file path in question. Without a [mcve] we can only guess at the problem.

Comment: How long are your absolute path names?  256 bytes?  1024 bytes?  Longer?  There are limits like `NAME_MAX` for individual file components (between a pair of slashes, or after the last slash, or before the first slash) and `PATH_MAX` for the sum of the lengths of all the components in a file name.  There are lower bounds on those limits, too: `_POSIX_NAME_MAX`, `_XOPEN_NAME_MAX`, `_POSIX_PATH_MAX`, `_XOPEN_PATH_MAX` all in [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html).

Comment: If you really have path names that are too long, you may have to use [`openat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html) to open a directory part way along the full name, and maybe then use that in a subsequent call to open another directory (and repeat as needed) until you can use it to open the file relative to the last directory you `openat()`'d.  You should be able to traverse multiple levels of the directory hierarchy on each `openat()` call.  Frankly, though, you should be reconsidering why the names are so long that they cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you should use `_wfopen()`. Look at this [Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2017) of `_wfopen()`.

In a example the can be found [at this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829691/opening-long-file-names-in-windows-using-fopen-with-c), it teaches you to do a cross-platform file opening:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    myFile = _wfopen( ... );
#else
    myFile = fopen( ... );
#endif
```

Comment: I took a look at a post which stated that exactly. I didn't mention I'm working under Linux.